# Looking for a way to compare appearances of combinations in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, bigdata

i have a BI task that seem to me very interesting and i would like to get some help in order to solve it.
I have 2 Data Sets - Conversions and Clicks.
Conversions Table:

```
 id     Rev    Click_id     
  1      2$      1            
  2      3$      2            
  3      1$      3
  4      2$      5
```

The Clicks Table:

```
   id     Date      Click_data
    1      2.6.2015 {"country:US","Device:Android","Domain:a.com"}
    2      2.6.2015 {"country:US","Device:Android","Domain:b.com",Size=300X250}
    3      2.6.2015 {"country:GB","Device:Android","Domain:b.com",Size=300X250}
    4      2.6.2015 {"country:GB","Device:iphone","Domain:b.com",Size=300X50}
    5      2.6.2015 {"country:GB","Device:iphone","Domain:b.com"}
    6      2.6.2015 {"country:GB","Device:Android","Domain:b.com"}
    7      2.6.2015 {"country:GB","Device:iphone","Domain:b.com"}
    8      2.6.2015 {"country:GB","Device:Android","Domain:b.com","Size=300X250"}
```

The Click Data is always in JSON Format and can have 1 - N Fields
Now what i want to get is the following results:
I need to find the combination of click data that converts

Stage 1 - The Best Combination base on the conversion Data:

```
  count   country     device    size     Domain
   1        US      "ANDROID"    ''       "a.com"
   2        US      "ANDROID"  '300X250'  "b.com"
   1        GB      "IPHONE"     ''       "b.com"
```

Now i got to this stage allowing flexible Group by count out of the Text field with Some PHP code that create a list of Dimensions Json Values for creating a Query.
Query Sample :

PHP code -> Generate a list of dimensions for counting

Query:

```
    SELECT 
    count(*)as count,
    trim( both "}" from      substring_index(substring_index(if(locate('"country":',click_data) > 0,click_data, null), '"country":',-1),',',1)) as country,

    trim( both "}" from           substring_index(substring_index(if(locate('"Device":',click_data) > 0,click_data, null), '"Device":',-1),',',1)) as Device,

    trim( both "}" from      substring_index(substring_index(if(locate('"Domain":',click_data) > 0,click_data, null), '"country":',-1),',',1)) as Domain,

    trim( both "}" from      substring_index(substring_index(if(locate('"Size":',click_data) > 0,click_data, null), '"country":',-1),',',1)) as Size,

    group by
    trim( both "}" from      substring_index(substring_index(if(locate('"country":',click_data) > 0,click_data, null), '"country":',-1),',',1)) as country,

    trim( both "}" from           substring_index(substring_index(if(locate('"Device":',click_data) > 0,click_data, null), '"Device":',-1),',',1)) as Device,

    trim( both "}" from      substring_index(substring_index(if(locate('"Domain":',click_data) > 0,click_data, null), '"country":',-1),',',1)) as Domain,

    trim( both "}" from      substring_index(substring_index(if(locate('"Size":',click_data) > 0,click_data, null), '"country":',-1),',',1)) as Size

   ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

Now i am looking to do the same with the Click Table and at the same Query so i could create this Result:

```
 Stage 1 - The Best Combination

Count_clicks  count_convs   country     device    size     Domain
      1            1          US      "ANDROID"    ''       "a.com"
      3            2          US      "ANDROID"  '300X250'  "b.com"
      2            1          GB      "IPHONE"     ''       "b.com"
```

I am looking to find a way to add the counts of the click aggregated by the Json Sub String actions ( you can look at this as dimensions) to the similar counts at the conversions in order to see how many clicks where generated by this combination in order to get the real Conversion Rate.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: So is your question how *not* to use string functions on JSON, cleaning up the data to a point that the math is trivial and your question moot?

Comment: I would think that you would want to perform some sort of ETL (extract, transform, load) job on this data to place it into a suitable format before trying to work with it from a data warehouse standpoint.  Your data are hopelessly formatted for trying to use for analytics purposes and you will pull your hair out trying to work with it in the format in which you are recording it. This is not to mention that your data analytics queries will be horrendously slow since you are not using any sort of indexing.

Comment: You will have a horrible headache trying to parse json in sql like that. The data should really not be in the database in a serialized format for you to try to parse. This is pretty much the same as combining several columns worth of data into a single column and trying to query off that. It is a nightmare.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for delaying response.. first , you are right this a messed up way to run SQL Query i am running a New DB POC for SQreamDB and this a case study, Second this a varible data size that contains 10 - 200 Dimension base on the Traffic source. ETL proccess is already done at this stage and there other 18 fixed dimension, this is all the other fields that we keep on the DB just for some late analytics.. putting the json issue aside. do you have any idea ho to join base on this break down?